# Bad Request 400: Ao acessar API com Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2, ionic3

Estou recebendo em meu console a resposta de Bad Request 400 para a chamada de minha API:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu app.api.ts na pasta app está:

```
export const MEAT_API = 'http://localhost:1337'
```

E meu código principal está:

```
submit(){
    var link = 'http://localhost:1337/user/login';
    var data = '?email='+JSON.stringify(this.usuario.email)+'&senha='+ JSON.stringify(this.usuario.senha);


    this.http.post(link, data)
      .subscribe(data => {
       this.data.response = data._body;

       if(this.data.response != "[]"){
        var resposta = this.data.response;
        console.log(resposta);

        // tinha que pegar o ID do usuário.... :/
         sessionStorage.setItem("usuarioEmail", this.usuario.email);
         //sessionStorage.setItem("idUsusario", resposta[0].idusuarios);
         sessionStorage.setItem("flagLogado", "sim");

         this.navCtrl.setRoot(WellFitPage, {}, {animate: true, direction: "forward"});
        }else{
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Usuário Não encontrado!',
            subTitle: 'Verifique se digitou seu e-mail e senha corretamente.',
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present();
       }
    })
  }
```

Estou migrando do Ionic 1 para o 3 muita coisa mudou. O que pode ser? Minha API foi desenvolvida utilizando o SailsJS.

Em meus Postman, parece certo, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
const link = 'http://localhost:1337/user/login';
const options =
   { 
       params: new HttpParams()
                  .set('email', this.usuario.email)
                  .set('senha', this.usuario.senha)
    };


    this.http.post(link, options )
```

Uma dica normalmente vc retorna o observable do seu serviço e faz o subscribe no componente.